# Directly generating specific subsets of a powerset?

Tags: haskell, set, combinations

Haskell's expressiveness enables us to rather easily define a powerset function:

```
import Control.Monad (filterM)

powerset :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerset = filterM (const [True, False])
```

To be able to perform my task it is crucial for said powerset to be sorted by a specific function, so my implementation kind of looks like this:

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

powersetBy :: Ord b => ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
powersetBy f = sortBy (comparing f) . powerset
```

Now my question is whether there is a way to only generate a **subset** of the powerset given a specific `start` and `end`point, where `f(start) < f(end)` and `|start| < |end|`. For example, my parameter is a list of integers (`[1,2,3,4,5]`) and they are sorted by their sum. Now I want to extract only the subsets in a given range, lets say `3` to `7`. One way to achieve this would be to `filter` the powerset to only include my range but this seems (and is) ineffective when dealing with larger subsets:

```
badFunction :: Ord b => b -> b -> ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
badFunction start end f = filter (\x -> f x >= start && f x <= end) . powersetBy f
```

`badFunction 3 7 sum [1,2,3,4,5]` produces `[[1,2],[3],[1,3],[4],[1,4],[2,3],[5],[1,2,3],[1,5],[2,4],[1,2,4],[2,5],[3,4]]`.

Now my question is whether there is a way to generate this list directly, without having to generate all `2^n` subsets first, since it will improve performance drastically by not having to check all elements but rather generating them "on the fly".

Comment: For an arbitrary ordering function you can't really do better.  Look for structure in your ordering function that you can exploit.

Comment: What is the ordering function or what are its properties?  Without some knowledge about the function, you can't do better - consider for example the function to be a [cryptographic hash funciton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to allow for completely general ordering-functions, then there *can't* be a way around checking all elements of the powerset. (After all, how would you know the isn't a special clause built in that gives, say, the particular set `[6,8,34,42]` a completely different ranking from its neighbours?)

However, you could make the algorithm already drastically faster by

1. Only sorting *after* filtering: sorting is *O* (*n* · log *n*), so you want keep *n* low here; for the *O* (*n*) filtering step it matters less. (And anyway, number of elements doesn't change through sorting.)
2. Apply the ordering-function only once to each subset.

So

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))

lessBadFunction :: Ord b => (b,b) -> ([a]->b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
lessBadFunction (start,end) f
     = map snd . sortBy (comparing fst)
               . filter (\(k,_) -> k>=start && k<=end)
               . map (f &&& id)
               . powerset
```

Basically, let's face it, powersets of anything but a very small basis are infeasible. The particular application “sum in a certain range” is pretty much a [packaging problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems); there are quite efficient ways to do that kind of thing, but you'll have to give up the idea of perfect generality and of quantification over general subsets.

Answer (score 2):

Since your problem is essentially a constraint satisfaction problem, using an external SMT solver might be the better alternative here; assuming you can afford the extra IO in the type and the need for such a solver to be installed. The SBV library allows construction of such problems. Here's one encoding:

```
import Data.SBV

-- c is the cost type
-- e is the element type
pick :: (Num e, SymWord e, SymWord c) => c -> c -> ([SBV e] -> SBV c) -> [e] -> IO [[e]]
pick begin end cost xs = do
        solutions <- allSat constraints
        return $ map extract $ extractModels solutions
  where extract ts  = [x | (t, x) <- zip ts xs, t]
        constraints = do tags <- mapM (const free_) xs
                         let tagged    = zip tags xs
                             finalCost = cost [ite t (literal x) 0 | (t, x) <- tagged]    
                         solve [finalCost .>= literal begin, finalCost .<= literal end]

test :: IO [[Integer]]
test = pick 3 7 sum [1,2,3,4,5]
```

We get:

```
Main> test
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,2,3],[1,4],[1,2,4],[1,5],[2,5],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4],[3],[4],[5]]
```

For large lists, this technique will beat out generating all subsets and filtering; assuming the cost function generates reasonable constraints. (Addition will be typically OK, if you've multiplications, the backend solver will have a harder time.)

(As a side note, you should never use `filterM (const [True, False])` to generate power-sets to start with! While that expression is cute and fun, it is extremely inefficient!)